# Type mismatch when importing from Pandas to SQLAlchemy Declarative Class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, casting, type-conversion

The code actually works but big red flag as pyright detects a type mismatch.
When I import from a csv file to a Pandas dataframe and then instantiate

```
 company = Company(name=df['name'][index],
                          url=df['url'][index],
                          stype=df['stype'][index],
                          base_selector=df['base_selector'][index],
                          name_selector=df['name_selector'][index],
                          price_selector=df['price_selector'][index],
                          eos_type=df['eos_type'][index],
                          eos_element=df['eos_element'][index])
```

I get the following mismatch error

```
 Argument of type "Series | Any | ndarray[Any, Unknown] | Unknown | NDArray[Unknown] | DataFrame" cannot be assigned to parameter "stype" of type "SQLCoreOperations[str]
```

This is completely understandable as the ORM class attribute identifies itself as

```
type(Company.name)
PyDev console: starting.
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>
```

My question: What can I do to re-cast to the correct type. Below is the Declarative class.

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "companies"
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), primary_key=True, init=True, unique=True)
    url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    stype: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10))
    base_selector: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    name_selector: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    price_selector: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    eos_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    eos_element: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    prices: Mapped[list["Item"]] = relationship("Item", back_populates="company", init=False)
```